# How prove this equality $4064b^6+4064c^6+1452b^2c^4+8013b^4c^2+7172b^3c^3-4728b^5c-11289bc^5\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

let $b,c\ge 0$, show that
$$4064b^6+4064c^6+1452b^2c^4+8013b^4c^2+7172b^3c^3-4728b^5c-11289bc^5\ge 0$$

my idea
let $\dfrac{c}{b}=x$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 4064x^6+1452x^4+8013x^2+7172x^3-4278x-11289x^5\ge 0$$
and I can't prove that

and my other idea I think we can
$$4064b^4+4064c^6+1452b^2c^4+8013b^4c^2+7172b^3c^3-4728b^5c-11289bc^5=(\cdots+\cdots)^2+(b-c)^2(\cdots+\cdots)+(\cdots+\cdots)$$

Comment: This (as formulated) is not true: put $c=1$ and $b$ big.

Comment: when $c=1$, if $b$ is big then $4064b^4$ is bigger too..

Comment: Do you take into consideration $-4728b^5c$?

Comment: Have you have example ?Thank you

Comment: The Maple command $$eval(-4728*b^5*c+8013*b^4*c^2+7172*b^3*c^3+1452*b^2*c^4-11289*b*c^5+4064*c^6+4064*b^4, [c = 1, b = 10]) $$ outputs $-344821626 $.

Comment: I have  edit,Thank you

Comment: if you substitute $x$ for $\dfrac{c}{b}$ you get
$$4064 + 4064x^6+1452x^4+8013x^2+7172x^3-4278x-11289x^5\ge 0$$
you forgot the constant term

Comment: a numerical investigation$$4064\,x^6-4728\,x^5+8013\,x^4+7172\,x^3+1452\,x^2-11289\,x+4064=0$$
Mathematica shows only [complex solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4064*x%5E6-4728*x%5E5%2B8013*x%5E4%2B7172*x%5E3%2B1452*x%5E2-11289*x%2B4064%3D0)
So the term is always greater than $0$.
Setting the derivate to zero 

$$24384\,x^5-23640\,x^4+32052\,x^3+21516\,x^2+2904\,x-11289=0$$
shows that there is one [optimum (a minimum)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=24384*x%5E5-23640*x%5E4%2B32052*x%5E3%2B21516*x%5E2%2B2904*x-11289%3D0)
 at $x=0.525408$.

Answer (score 2):

[Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) tells the number of real roots of a polynomial in a finite or unfinite interval:

If $f$ is a polynomial with no multiple zeroes and 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
p_0&=&f \\
p_1&=&f' \\
&\ldots& \\
p_{k}&=&q_{k-1} p_{k-1}-p_{k-2}, \;2 \le k \le \deg(f) 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
(so $p_k$ is $-\text{remainder}(p_{k-2},p_{k-1})$).
$s(x)$ is defined as the number of sign changes (ignoring zeroes) of the sequence $p_0(x),p_1(x),\ldots,p_n(x)$. The number of zeroes 
in the interval $(a,b]$ is $s(a)-s(b)$. $a$ or $b$ may be finite or infinite.

We get the following polynomials

$$\begin{eqnarray}
p_0(x)&=&4064\,x^6-4728\,x^5+8013\,x^4+7172\,x^3+1452\,x^2-11289\,x+4064 \\
p_1(x)&=&24384\,x^5-23640\,x^4+32052\,x^3+21516\,x^2+2904\,x-11289 \\
p_2(x)&=&-{{484389\,x^4}\over{254}}-{{2347875\,x^3}\over{508}}-{{844965\,x^2
 }\over{508}}+{{1182834\,x}\over{127}}-{{7516737}\over{2032}} \\
p_3(x)&=&-{{612066329796312\,x^3}\over{2896700041}}-{{616315839551784\,x^2
 }\over{2896700041}}+{{1299056386804560\,x}\over{2896700041}}-{{
 432179733271266}\over{2896700041}} \\
p_4(x)&=&{{3403397485884951981152330679\,x^2}\over{1138041922056745670480366
 }}-{{22426186423625229113319176235\,x}\over{
 4552167688226982681921464}}+{{8155852251219172953068259573}\over{
 4552167688226982681921464}} \\
p_5(x)&=&{{3827048533652960029223608784473907553510217884267\,x}\over{
 10970446132264674575437297042395420599696738}}-{{
 2049303196318674424207560097004880809709210563853}\over{
 10970446132264674575437297042395420599696738}} \\
p_2(x)&=&-{{
 87271241884134221974057024717741032712682877195704444368345339216133241
 }\over{
 7846204674359969455678504421998848204946056002763352820784652217706206
 }} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

From the leading coefficients we get the sign sequence
$$ + + - - + + -$$
for $x=\infty$ and the sequence
$$+ - - + + - - $$
for $x=-\infty$
so $$s(\infty)-s(-\infty)=3-3=0$$
So there is  no root in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I tried more direct methods, e.g.

if $x \le -1$ then

$$4064x^6-4728x^5+8013x^4+7172x^3+1452x^2-11289x+4064 
\ge 4064x^6-4728x^5+ (8013*(-1)+7172)x^3+1452x^2-11289x+4064 
\gt 0$$

So $f(x)>0$ if  $x  \in (-\infty,1)$

The taylor expansion in $\frac{10}{19}$ is

$${{3790731474}\over{47045881}}+{{107236629\,\left(x-{{10}\over{19}}
 \right)}\over{2476099}}+{{3111904332\,\left(x-{{10}\over{19}}\right)
 ^2}\over{130321}}+{{156348468\,\left(x-{{10}\over{19}}\right)^3
 }\over{6859}}+{{4497093\,\left(x-{{10}\over{19}}\right)^4}\over{361
 }}+{{154008\,\left(x-{{10}\over{19}}\right)^5}\over{19}}+4064\,
 \left(x-{{10}\over{19}}\right)^6 $$

so the $f(x)>0$ if $x>{{10}\over{19}}$.

But the polynomial $f$ has the complex roots 
$$\left[ x=0.0581\,i+0.527 , x=0.527-0.0581\,i , x=0.653\,i-0.809 , x=
 -0.653\,i-0.809 , x=1.5949\,i+0.864 , x=0.864-1.5949\,i \right] $$

So the polynomial has two conjugate roots near $0.527$ ($\approx \frac{10}{19}$, a continuus fraction approximation) and I was not able to proceed in the above  way near these zeroes.